# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError in Python 3.12 interpreter

Tags: modulenotfounderror, python-3.12

I have installed the fibo module in system:

```
PS C:\Users\Dell> pip install fibo
Requirement already satisfied: fibo in c:\users\Dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)
```

But it is showing ModuleNotFoundError in Python interpreter 3.12:

```
>>> import fibo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'
```

I want to use the module in the Python interpreter. How do I fix this problem?